# How to remove unwanted character from log files created by Winston

Tags: nestjs, winston, nest-winston

I am using Winston logger inside NestJS application but when logs are writing in file then some unwanted characters are also get appended to my logs.

Below are the logs from log file:

```
[92m[MyApp][39m [33mInfo[39m    16/3/2022, 7:03:52 pm [92mHello[39m - {}
```

Below is my Winston configuration :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonModule,utilities as nestWinstonModuleUtilities } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import * as path from 'path';

@Module({
imports: [ WinstonModule.forRoot({
          format: winston.format.combine(
                   winston.format.timestamp(),
                   winston.format.json(),
                   winston.format.simple(),
                   nestWinstonModuleUtilities.format.nestLike('MyApp', { prettyPrint: true }),
                  ),
          transports: [
                      new winston.transports.File({
                      dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../log/info/'), //path to where save logging result 
                      filename: 'info.txt', //name of file where will be saved logging result
                      level: 'info',
                    }),
                  ],        
       }),],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I remove these characters from my logs?

Comment: The characters are coming from color encoding. If you disable coloring in your logs they will go away

Comment: How can I disable coloring

Answer (score 0):

Add format like this. You can change replace character whatever you want. This code is for example.

```
new winston.transports.File({
                      dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../log/info/'), //path to where save logging result 
                      filename: 'info.txt', //name of file where will be saved logging result
                      level: 'info',
                      format: format.combine(
                             format.printf((i) => i.message.replace('e', '')),
                        ),
                    }),
```

Or if you want to delete all special character use this code

```
new winston.transports.File({
                      dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../log/info/'), //path to where save logging result 
                      filename: 'info.txt', //name of file where will be saved logging result
                      level: 'info',
                      format: format.combine(
                             format.printf((i) => i.message.replace(/[e]/g, '')),
                        ),
                    }),
```